# Using parse API in swift 3, only some query results are saving?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-ec2, parse-server

I'm new to `Swift` and programming. I'm using `Xcode 8.2.1` and the `Parse AWS` (free) server.

I'm using the following Syntax in order to save all `query` results for specific `object IDs` in to one row of a new `parse class`.

Most of the `query` results are saving (e.g. primarycityquery, secondcityquery, citydetailsquery) but not all (e.g. multicityquery).

I'm using the exact same syntax in another `UIViewController` (with just 3 `queries`, though) and it's working fine.

Is the issue here that I'm running too many queries? This is all within `viewDidLoad`. Please advise if there is a better way to do this, as well.

Thank you!

```
    let primaryCityQuery = PFQuery(className: "primaryCityDetails")

    primaryCityQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: passedPrimaryCityDetailsObjectIdString)

    primaryCityQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
        if let objects = objects {


            for primaryCityQuery in objects {

                if let primaryCity = primaryCityQuery["primaryCity"] as? String {

                    self.primaryCity = String(primaryCity)

                    print(self.primaryCity) }

                if let primaryCountry = primaryCityQuery["primaryCountry"] as? String {

                    self.primaryCountry = String(primaryCountry)

                    print(self.primaryCountry) }

                if let primaryState = primaryCityQuery["primaryState"] as? String {

                    self.primaryState = String(primaryState)

                    print(self.primaryState) }

                if let numberDays = primaryCityQuery["numberDays"] as? String {

                    self.numberDays = String(numberDays)

                    print(self.numberDays) }

                if let numberNights = primaryCityQuery["numberNights"] as? String {

                    self.numberNights = String(numberNights)

                    print(self.numberNights) }



            } } else {

            print(error!)

        } })

    //second city info 

    let secondCityQuery = PFQuery(className: "secondCityDetails")

    secondCityQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: passedSecondCityDetailsObjectIDString)

    secondCityQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

        if let objects = objects {

            for secondCityQuery in objects {

                if let secondCity = secondCityQuery["secondCity"] as? String {

                    self.secondCity = String(secondCity)

                    print(self.secondCity) }

                if let secondCountry = secondCityQuery["secondCountry"] as? String {

                    self.secondCountry = String(secondCountry)

                    print(self.secondCountry) }

                if let secondState = secondCityQuery["secondState"] as? String {

                    self.secondState = String(secondState)

                    print(self.secondState) }


            } } else {

                    print(error!)

            } })

           //


        let multiCityQuery = PFQuery(className: "multiCityDetails")

                    multiCityQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: passedCityBeforeDetailsObjectIdString)

                    multiCityQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

                        if let objects = objects {

                            for multiCityQuery in objects {

                                if let beforeCity = multiCityQuery["beforeCity"] as? String {

                                    self.beforeCity = String(beforeCity)

                                    print(self.beforeCity) }

                                if let beforeCountry = multiCityQuery["beforeCountry"] as? String {

                                    self.beforeCountry = String(beforeCountry)

                                    print(self.beforeCountry) }


                                if let beforeState = multiCityQuery["beforeState"] as? String {

                                    self.beforeState = String(beforeState)

                                    print(self.beforeState) }

                            } } else {

                            print(error!)

                        } })


    let inputtedCityDetailsQuery = PFQuery(className: "primaryTripDetails")

        inputtedCityDetailsQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: primTripDetails)

        inputtedCityDetailsQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

            if let objects = objects {

                for inputtedCityDetailsQuery in objects {

                    if let primaryTripWhen = inputtedCityDetailsQuery["primaryTripWhen"] as? String {

                        self.primaryTripWhen = String(primaryTripWhen)

                        print(self.primaryTripWhen) }

                    if let primaryTripWhatSort = inputtedCityDetailsQuery["primaryTripWhatSort"] as? String {

                        self.primaryTripWhatSort = String(primaryTripWhatSort)

                        print(self.primaryTripWhatSort) }

                    if let primaryTripWhoWith = inputtedCityDetailsQuery["primaryTripWhoWith"] as? String {

                        self.primaryTripWhoWith = String(primaryTripWhoWith)

                        print(self.primaryTripWhoWith) }

                    if let primaryTripBudget = inputtedCityDetailsQuery["primaryTripBudget"] as? String {

                        self.primaryTripBudget = String(primaryTripBudget)

                        print(self.primaryTripBudget)



                let fullCityInput = PFObject(className: "fullCityInputRow")

                    fullCityInput["primaryCity"] = self.primaryCity
                    fullCityInput["primaryCountry"] = self.primaryCountry
                    fullCityInput["primaryState"] = self.primaryState
                    fullCityInput["secondCity"] = self.secondCity
                    fullCityInput["secondCountry"] = self.secondCountry
                    fullCityInput["secondState"] = self.secondState

                    fullCityInput["beforeCity"] = self.beforeCity
                    fullCityInput["beforeCountry"] = self.beforeCountry
                    fullCityInput["beforeState"] = self.beforeState
                    fullCityInput["primaryTripWhoWith"] = self.primaryTripWhoWith
                    fullCityInput["primaryTripBudget"] = self.primaryTripBudget
                    fullCityInput["primaryTripWhen"] = self.primaryTripWhen
                    fullCityInput["primaryTripWhatSort"] = self.primaryTripWhatSort

                    fullCityInput["numberDays"] = self.numberDays
                    fullCityInput["numberNights"] = self.numberNights

                fullCityInput.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) in

                            if success {

                                print("full city input row saved")

                            } else {

                                if error != nil {

                                    print (error!)
                                } else {

                                    print("blanks")
                                }
                            }
                        })

                    }
                }

            } else {

            print(error!)

        } })
```

Comment: Welcome to SO user7811828. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In short, describe what errors you encounter, and what you run into when you are debugging the sample you provided. I am sure nobody has access to your custom setup of Parse and Amazon. Does this stop at the magical number 3 ? or does it work for some other limit of query etc?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. It does seem the magic number is 3. I've saved the values that were not saving in this view controller to another and then query them in one of my 3 queries here. All of my inputs are now successfully saved in one row of another class.